# Multiple values per day for Serial Chart? (AmChart)

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have a set of data including possible multiple values for a day.

I would like to plot each single record on the chart to see their distribution.

I tried using serial charts but the problems are 1) many records are missing from the chart (not sure why), and 2) the cursor only hovers the first entry (see the very first Y value [only first entry can be hovered](http://jsfiddle.net/CC82E/1/).)

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "graphs": [{
        "bullet": "round",
        "valueField": "value",
        "lineAlpha": 0
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "zoomable": false,
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
    },

    "dataProvider": [{
        "date": "2012-07-27",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-27",
        "value": 11
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-27",
        "value": 15
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-27",
        "value": 16
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-27",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-27",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-02",
        "value": 22
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-03",
        "value": 23
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-04",
        "value": 20
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-05",
        "value": 17
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-06",
        "value": 16
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-07",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-08",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-09",
        "value": 26
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-10",
        "value": 24
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-11",
        "value": 29
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-12",
        "value": 32
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-13",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-14",
        "value": 24
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-15",
        "value": 22
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-16",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-17",
        "value": 19
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-18",
        "value": 14
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-19",
        "value": 15
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-20",
        "value": 12
    }]
}
```

);

Is there any workaround?
I also tried XY Chart, but it doesn't have the date support.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one data item per unique date in amCharts.

You should combine data points into one, like:

```
{"date":"2012-08-27","value1":10,"value2":12,"value3":14}
```

and create a separate graph for each value field.

Comment: But wouldn't that will introduce too many graphs with legends.

Comment: You can hide graphs from legends if you want by setting graph.visibleInLegend = false;

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but I really like the effect that users can click on the legend to filter the data. I really wonder why XY chart does not support date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.Suddenly, someone will need

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    categoryAxesSettings: {
      minPeriod: "hh",//(at least that is not grouped)
      groupToPeriods : ["DD", "WW","MM"]//(Data will be grouped by day,week and month)
    }
  });
```

[more](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/)